# Angular pikaday date formatting

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, pikaday

I'm using `angular-pikaday` plugin (https://github.com/nverba/angular-pikaday) and I have a problem with a date formatting.

What I need to get is a model with a string of date in format `YYYY-MM-dd`.

I've installed `Moment.js` through bower (as documentation says that it's needed). Part of code looks like this (angular-pikaday.coffee)

```
picker = new Pikaday(
      field: elem[0]
      trigger: document.getElementById(attrs.triggerId)
      bound: attrs.bound isnt "false"
      position: attrs.position or ""
      format: "YYYY-MM-dd" # Requires Moment.js for custom formatting
      defaultDate: new Date()
      setDefaultDate: attrs.setDefaultDate is "true"
      firstDay: 1
      ( ... )
```

How can I put formatted date inside ng-model passed in HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Date = {{ myPickerObject.getDate() | date:'YYYY-MM-dd' }}
```

**UPD:**

```
$filter('data')(myPickerObject.getDate(), 'YYYY-MM-dd' )
```

Comment: I need formatted date inside model, not in html. Because I need to use it to sent it with AJAX

Comment: There is a typo - it is `$filter('date')` (dat**a** -> dat**e**)